# Export neo4j graph to graphml using apoc Neo4j 4.0.1

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, graphml

I want to export a graph in neo4j to graphML so I can load it up in `networkx`. I was following the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/export/graphml/#export-graphml-whole-database) to export using `apoc` but cannot seem to get this line running: 
`CALL apoc.export.graphml.all("movies.graphml", {})`. This is the error:

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
>   Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.graphml.all`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Export to files not enabled, please set apoc.export.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

I get the same error when I try to run this on the sandbox even though it does apoc.export.graphml because export is not activated in config. I looked through the config file and cannot find this line to uncomment :(

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
>   Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.graphml.all`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Export to files not enabled, please set apoc.export.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

Looking for help to export a graph to graphml - please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was silly of me. This post had the [`answer`](https://medium.com/@niazangels/export-and-import-your-neo4j-graph-easily-with-apoc-4ea614f7cbdf)

You apparently have to add these lines manually to the config:

`dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.export.*,apoc.import.*` `apoc.export.file.enabled=true`
`apoc.import.file.enabled=true`

Comment: I didn't get the error but I can't find the file!  Where does the file get written?